# If ELSE / ELSE statement is not showing up

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-designer-workflow, if-statement

I want to use IF ELSE statement in the SharePoint designer 2013 but it is not showing up I am trying to get else by pressing Alt + W + B but sometimes it works, other times it doesn't. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Click anywhere in the **IF** block.
2. Then you can see the **Else** block in ribbon or workflow actions.

[image]

Also check this blog: [Else Branch is disabled In SharePoint Designer](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/else-branch-disabled-sharepoint-designer/).

Comment: Great thank you!!!! I will accept the answer after 10 mins. Nice one